# Why does this need an explicit std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I got a `Foo` class containing an `std::vector` constructed from `std::unique_ptr` objects of another class, `Bar`.

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Bar> UniqueBar;

class Foo {
    std::vector<UniqueBar> bars;
public:
    void AddBar(UniqueBar&& bar);
};

void Foo::AddBar(UniqueBar&& bar) {
    bars.push_back(bar);
}
```

This one results in a compilation error (in g++ 4.8.1) saying that the the copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is deleted, which is reasonable. The question here is, since the bar argument is already an rvalue reference, why does the copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is called instead of its move constructor?

If I explicitly call `std::move` in `Foo::AddBar` then the compilation issue goes away but I don't get why this is needed. I think it's quite redundant.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, every object which has a name is an lvalue. When you pass an object to a function using an rvalue reference the function actually sees an lvalue: it is named. What the rvalue reference does, however, indicate is that it came from an object which is ready to be transferred.

Put differently, rvalue references are assymmetrical:

- they can only receive rvalues, i.e., either temporary objects, objects about to go away, or objects which look as if they are rvalues (e.g., the result of `std::move(o)`)
- the rvalue reference itself looks, however, like an lvalue

Answer (score 9):

Confusing as it might seem, an *rvalue-reference* binds to an *rvalue*, but used as an expression is an *lvalue*.

Answer (score 8):

`bar` is actually an lvalue, so you need to pass it through `std::move`, so that it is seen as an rvalue in the call to `push_back`.

The `Foo::AddBar(UniqueBar&& bar)` overload simply ensures that this overload is picked when an rvalue is passed in a call to `Foo::AddBar`. But the `bar` argument itself has a name and is an lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

`bar` is defined as an rvalue-reference, but its *value-category* is an lvalue. This is so because the object has a name. If it has a name, it's an lvalue. Therefore an explicit `std::move` is necessary because the intention is to get rid of the name and return an xvalue (eXpiring-rvalue).