# c++ why is move/forward necessary in moving constructor

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue

After constructing an object with a moving constructor, the new object should "steal" the resources of the "source" object, which is then left in an indefinite (but valid) state.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void print(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::cout << "size = " << v.size() << " vector = ";
    for (const auto& x : v)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data(10, 3);
    std::cout << "data:" << std::endl;
    print(data);

    std::vector<int> data2(std::move(data));
    std::cout << "data2:" << std::endl;
    print(data2);
    std::cout << "data after moving:" << std::endl;
    print(data);

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55323e23922da549).

As far as I know the standard does not specify the content of `data` after having called the moving constructor, however one would expect that the resources of `data` have been stolen by `data2`. And indeed, the output the program above shows that:

```
data:
size = 10 vector = 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
data2:
size = 10 vector = 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
data after moving:
size = 0 vector =
```

Now consider a slight variation of the above program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
    std::vector<int> m_data;
public:
    A(std::vector<int>&& data) : m_data{data} { }
    const std::vector<int>& data() const { return m_data; }
};

template <class T>
void print(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::cout << "size = " << v.size() << " vector = ";
    for (const auto& x : v)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data(10, 3);
    std::cout << "data:" << std::endl;
    print(data);

    A x{std::move(data)};
    std::cout << "x.data():" << std::endl;
    print(x.data());
    std::cout << "data after moving:" << std::endl;
    print(data);

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44271cb14b5b5c52).

I am surprised by output of the program:

```
data:
size = 10 vector = 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
x.data():
size = 10 vector = 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
data after moving:
size = 10 vector = 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

It looks like the vector `data` has been just copied to `A::m_data` rather then being moved.

If I substitute the moving constructor of A with

```
A(std::vector<int>&& data) : m_data{std::move(data)} { }
```

(see it [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b3bc96259786cd4))

or with

```
A(std::vector<int>&& data) : m_data{std::forward<std::vector<int>&&>(data)} { }
```

(see it [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1a7d204967f34b2))

then the output of the program resembles that of the first code

```
data:
size = 10 vector = 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
x.data():
size = 10 vector = 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
data after moving:
size = 0 vector =
```

In other words, it seems that either `std:move` or `std::forward` are necessary to effectively call the moving constructor of `A::m_data`. Both `std::move` and `std::forward` return a `static_cast` to `std::vector<int>&&`, but the argument of the moving constructor of `A` is already a rvalue.

Why is an additional `std::move` or `std::forward` necessary?

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321145/why-does-this-need-an-explicit-stdmove or etc.

Comment: `A(std::vector<int>&& data) : m_data{data}, m_data2{data} {}` is perfectly legal, so that first thing had better not obliterate `data`!!

Comment: When you use `data` as an expression, the type of this expression is adjusted to be a non-reference type `std::vector<int>`. No `&`, no `&&`. How should the compiler know which constructor to call? Value category. `data` has lvalue category and cannot bind to `std::vector<int>&&` in a move constructor. To change the value category you use move: `std::move(data)` has xvalue category and can bind to `std::vector<int>&&`. It will be a better match than copy ctor. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716647/rvalues-lvalues-and-formal-definitions) if this sounds confusing.

Answer (score 1):

First your should know that `A::A(std::vector<int>&& data)` means that data is rvalue reference to `std::vector<T>`, just means reference not a call to move constructor,

and `A(std::vector<int>&& data) : m_data{data} { }` just calls copy constructor of `m_data` because `data` itself is a named value not a `r value` temporary in scope of `A::A` hence a `std::move` or `std::forward` is necessary.